# Gradle Junit 5 - use jar for testing

Tags: java, gradle, junit

Is it possible to set up junit tests & gradle in a way that the tests will be executed from a compiled jar?

For example my program utilizes method below.

```
public class Jar {

    public static File getFile() {
        URL clsUrl = Jar.class.getResource(Jar.class.getSimpleName() + ".class");
            try {
                URLConnection conn = clsUrl.openConnection();
                if (conn instanceof JarURLConnection) {
                    JarURLConnection connection = (JarURLConnection) conn;
                    return new File(connection.getJarFileURL().toURI().getSchemeSpecificPart());
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine as long as the Jar.class is within a jar file, however when within a junit test method call `openConnection()` return null.
In another part of my code i loop thru all classes within in the jar file to dynamically initialize some things - ie

`Enumeration<JarEntry> entries  = new JarFile(Jar.getFile()).entries()`

Such code works fine as long as its compiled within jar, but throws error when run from junit test.

Is there any workaround i could use to unit test this method without editing existing codebase?